Why is my @Published array getting cleared in the viewModel when I call a second swiftUI view?
I have an @Published var myAllCategories: [Category] = [], when I load my first view, I call an api to get all categories, then I call a functon called to loadMyMajorCategories which reads the myAllCategories and appends the ones I want for myMajorCategories.  This all works fine, and I have a print statement that will show that the myAllCategories still has elements in it after this.
My view changes to a new view where I want to display subCategories, so I call a function to loadMySubCategories, and I want to read my same myAllCategories array again, and I'll search for subCategoreis and append them to the mySubCategoreis array.
The problem is nothing is found, so I tried just appending all the records with no selection, still nothing.
So now I just put a print statement to display what is in the myAllCategories array, and I get an index Out of Bounds, because I attempted to access elements in the array but the array is empty.
How can my array be empty, it just had records in it when I called the loadMyMajorCategories()?
Is there something that is keeping the myAllCategories from persisting?
Thanks in advanced for any help or ideas that anyone can point me to.
Here's the view model and the two views
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class CategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    @Published var myAllCategories: [Category] = []
    @Published var myMajorCategories: [Category] = []
    @Published var mySubCategories: [Category] = []
    
    // Alert vars
    @Published var alertTitle = ""
    @Published var alertMessage = ""
    @Published var showApiAlert = false
    
    // MARK: - Categories
    func loadCategories() async {
        Service.sharedInstance.getCategoriesApi { categories in
            self.myAllCategories = categories.subcategories
            self.loadMyMajorCategories()
        } failure: { alertType, errorText in
        }
    }
    
    func loadMyMajorCategories() {
        for major in myAllCategories {
            if major.categoryLevel == 1 {
                myMajorCategories.append(major)
            }
        }
        print(" loadMajorCategories allCategories first element: \(myAllCategories[0].majorCategory)-\(myAllCategories[0].description)")
    }
    
    func loadMySubCategories(majorCategory: Category) {
        print(" filteredSubCategories() called")
        print(" filteredSubCategories allCategories first element: \(myAllCategories[0].majorCategory)-\(myAllCategories[0].description)")
        self.mySubCategories = myAllCategories.filter({
            $0.categoryLevel == 2
        })
    }
}


Here's the view for the major categories:
import SwiftUI

struct BrowseByCategoryView: View {
    
    var backPressed: ()->()
    
    @State private var categoryName = ""
    @StateObject private var vm = CategoryViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $vm.path){
            VStack {
                MyNavigationBar(
                    title: "Major Category",
                    backgroundColor: Color("browseByCatColor"),
                    navHeight: 48,
                    backText: "More",
                    backPressed: {
                        print(" BrowseByCategoryView --- backPressed() line \(#line)")
                        backPressed()
                    },
                    showAddButton: false,
                    addPressed: {}
                )
                CustomerInfoBar(backgroundColor: Color("browseByCatAccent"))
                
                List(vm.myMajorCategories, id: \.self) { category in
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        BrowseBySubView(majorCat: category)
                    }, label: {
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Text(category.description)
                                .frame(
                                    width: geometry.size.width * 0.90,
                                    height: geometry.size.height,
                                    alignment: .leading
                                )
                                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                    // Navigate to a list of items in this category
                                    print(" Will display items in \(category.description) category")
                                    categoryName = category.description
                                    vm.path.append("BrowseItems")
                                })
                                .listRowBackground(Color(.tertiarySystemBackground))
                        }
                    })
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { view in
                    if view == "BrowseItems" {
                        BrowseItemsView(
                            categoryName: categoryName,
                            backPressed: { backPressed()
                            })
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .task {
            // Use .task to run an asynchronous task before the view appears
            await vm.loadCategories()
        }
        //MARK: API Alerts
        // This presents API errors for the entire Returns module, everything called under ReturnsListView
        .alert(vm.alertTitle, isPresented: $vm.showApiAlert) {
            Button("OK") {}
        } message: {
            Text(vm.alertMessage)
        }
    }
}


Here's the view for the sub categories:
import SwiftUI

struct BrowseBySubView: View {
    var majorCat: Category
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State private var categoryName = ""
    @StateObject private var vm = CategoryViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $vm.path) {
            VStack {
                MyNavigationBar(
                    title: "Sub Category",
                    backgroundColor: Color("browseByCatColor"),
                    navHeight: 48,
                    backText: "Back",
                    backPressed: {
                        print(" BrowseBySubView --- backPressed() line \(#line)")
                        dismiss()
                    },
                    showAddButton: false,
                    addPressed: {}
                )
                CustomerInfoBar(backgroundColor: Color("browseByCatAccent"))
                
                Text("Test Text")
                Text("\(majorCat.majorCategory) - \(majorCat.description)")
                List(vm.mySubCategories, id: \.self) { subCat in
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        BrowseByMinorView(subCat: subCat)
                    }, label: {
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Text(subCat.description)
                                .frame(
                                    width: geometry.size.width * 0.90,
                                    height: geometry.size.height,
                                    alignment: .leading
                                )
                                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                    // Navigate to a list of items in this category
                                    print(" Will display items in \(majorCat.description) category")
                                    categoryName = subCat.description
                                    vm.path.append("BrowseItems")
                                })
                                .listRowBackground(Color(.tertiarySystemBackground))
                        }
                    })
                
                }
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { view in
                    if view == "BrowseItems" {
                        BrowseItemsView(
                            categoryName: categoryName,
                            backPressed: { dismiss() }
                        )
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
        // Use .onAppear to perform an action before this view appears
            print(" BrowseBySub.onAppear majorCatDescription: \(majorCat.description)")
            print(" BrowseBySub.onAppear majorCategory: \(majorCat.majorCategory)")
            vm.loadMySubCategories(majorCategory: majorCat)
        }
        //MARK: API Alerts
        .alert(vm.alertTitle, isPresented: $vm.showApiAlert) {
            Button("OK") {}
        } message: {
            Text(vm.alertMessage)
        }
    }
}



You have 2 different view models with no relations to each other. You should have only one @StateObject private var vm = CategoryViewModel() in your views hierarchy (BrowseByCategoryView). Pass that to the other views using .environment(vm) and receive it as @Environment(CategoryViewModel.self) private var vm. Note, you should not have multiple data arrays. Have one data array @Published var myAllCategories: [Category] = [] and use .filter. See
Monitoring data

Note also you should have only one NavigationStack, remove the one in BrowseBySubView

Use .task to call your async funcs and you can just remove the ObservableObject
